# What is the difference between .NET Framework and CLR Version

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, amazon-ec2, frameworks

I have Windows 2012 installed on two different Amazon EC2 instances.

On the first instance I'm running

> Windows 2012 Standard (.NET Framework V4.0.30319)

and on the other instance I'm running

> Windows 2012 R2 Standard (.NET CLR Version V4.0.30319)

What is the difference between the two .NET frameworks installed ?

Is there anything I need to be aware of when deploying Visual Studio .NET C# applications ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically Framework is CLR and some other stuff: [CLR + managed libraries and tools = Microsoft .NET Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/karinm/archive/2008/11/11/what-s-the-difference-between-clr-and-net-framework.aspx)

While deploying you might want to make sure you are providing all the necessary libraries along with your compiled solution. Also you might - though I didn't check that for myself - not find some tools like iisreg if the full framework is not present.